# Turn ringer to loud from vibrate when a particular contact calls

Tags: calls, tasker, vibration

What can I do to make my phone ringer switch from vibrate to loud when a particular contact calls?

I tried using Tasker and created a profile for a Phone state, when a contact calls > set ringer volume to max.

It works... like this: when my phone is vibrate, and I get a phone call from the contact, the ringer goes up to high... however the call is still is on vibrate. The new high ringer volume affects only subsequent calls (from any contact).

So it doesn't exactly work as you can see. What can I do?

I use Nexus 6p with Marshmallow.

Comment: Put your phone into priority interruption mode and star the contact for which you want the phone to ring. Then automatically your phone will ring with volume when that particular contact calls and it will vibrate for other calls

Comment: Can you tell us what is silent mode here? There is Total Silence/Alarms Only/Priority but no such thing as Silent in Marshmallow.

Comment: @Firelord I added "/silent" assuming that will be the same scenario, but I'm looking for a solution for when the phone is on vibrate. I'll edit the q-n

Comment: @ulmas Okay. Do you see a problem in the answer below? You've neither accepted it, nor mentioned any issue with it, yet it seems to me that the problem is unresolved. Can you explain the issue with that answer here or there so that other posters avoid it?

Comment: @Firelord I upvoted the comment that reflected my opinion about the asnwer :)

Comment: @BarathVutukuri Priority interruptions would disable any kind of notifications, which is why the question is about the vibrate scenario.

Comment: @ulmas priority interruption will allow starred contacts to be ringed without disablling the ringtone.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `Action -> Media -> Play Ringtone -> Type: Ringer` to your Tasker profile, to explicitly play the default ringtone after you set full volume. You can also apply a custom ringtone if you want.

Tested on Galaxy S5.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Yes, it works but how do you stop that ringtone then? I started my task, left the device untouched for an  hour and the device kept ringing the ringtone! Media Stop event didn't help either.

Comment: On KitKat and Lollipop the ringtone does not stop. Noted in the Tasker documentation: `In some Android versions ringtones will endlessly loop due to an Android bug.` For that we can use `Media -> Music Play` instead, followed by a `Music Stop`.

Comment: That issue appears to be present in stock Android 6.0.1 as well. Can you consider incorporating the info available in your comment into your answer? I'm sure I won't be alone here having that endless loop in Tasker.